# Skinning a cat called int, improved

Tags: java, object, parameters, integer

I have an Object which did represent an int.
I need different, fantastic and obscure ways that Object can be used for an int param.
I can only think of 5 variations to do this..

```
abstract void take(int i);

void run(){

    Object o = get();

    take( /* VARIATIONS */   );
}
```

VARIATIONS:

1. `o` //Hope for the best
2. `(Integer)o` //Casting
3. `New Integer(o.toString())` //Construct from string
4. `Integer.valueOf(o)` //valueOf
5. `New Integer(String.valueOf(o))` //Sort of the same as #3

I'm aware of the multitude of exceptions that could be thrown, which is not a concern here.

---

### Edit

Using reflection the value of field can be returned as an Object.
I then need to use this value in param for a method.
The assumption mal code makes with reflections is that the field type is always an int.
When assumption is true: 1-5 work.
When assumption is false && Field type == `String`: 3+5 work, 1,2+4 fail.
When assumption is false && Field type == `ArrayList<Character>`: 1-5 fail.

I need more variations to test.

This continues my work discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21910529/reflection-improvements-to-access-field-secret-when-field-type-is-unknown). It was answered that robustness can not be added to combat all the different parsed field types. But now I need to test and gather results for which variations pass and fail.
 I'm asking for variations of ways to produce the param value which are not rehashes of 1-5 (e.g 3 & 5 are a bit similar).

---

### From eltabo

1. new BigDecimal(o.toString()).intValue()
2. new BigInteger(o.toString()).intValue()
3. new Double(o.toString()).intValue()
4. new Float(o.toString()).intValue()
5. Integer.parseInt(o.toString())
6. javax.swing.text.NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(o.toString()).intValue()

Comment: What is your objective here? What does the integer mean?

Comment: "I need more variations to test". My objective is to test different variations of Malicious code against parsed src code. The mal code isn't aware that it is working on parsed src code, so proceeds with assumptions. I need to know different variations, that the mal code might use to convert Object to int. I then record the success or failure of the mal code variations against parsed src code.

Comment: I just need more unique variations to convert Object to int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll be damned if I understand you but if it helps:

```
new BigDecimal(o.toString()).intValue()
new BigInteger(o.toString()).intValue()
new Double(o.toString()).intValue()
new Float(o.toString()).intValue()
Integer.parseInt(o.toString())
javax.swing.text.NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(o.toString()).intValue()
```

Comment: Magic! this is exactly what I'm after. This is a small part of a larger piece of work and it is confusing, (that is kind of the point of my work).

Comment: I will loose precision with the Double and Float, is there any such issue with BigDecimal or BigInteger, I'm not familiar with these?

Comment: BigDecimal exists to avoid precision issues that you can find using float. But you can find overflow issues in all of these cases (new BigDecimal(Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1 + "").intValue() returns -2147483648)